# Can a MacBookPro6,1 drive a Dell U2713HM via DisplayPort?

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

I have a 17" MacBook Pro with mini-DisplayPort output - the model before Thunderbolt. On that basis buying a Thunderbolt display is out. It has switched Intel HD/Nvidia GT 330M graphics.

Dell have a new 27" model, the U2713HM - like the U2711 it has a multitude of inputs and it looks like it should be usable with my Mac if I just get a mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable. I think this is the one because it is affordable and the anti-glare coating is reported to be excellent compared to the heavy, sparkly U2711's coating. All the reviewers who aren't concerned with gaming love it, those that do note that the 22ms input lag is better than the 2711 has but is still pretty bad.

But has anyone actually done it? VGA, DVI and Thunderbolt I know about, but I want to be sure about this monitor before buying it. If I need to upgrade the Mac to drive a large external monitor that changes everything and the Thunderbolt 27" is back in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes - using the [Monoprice 3ft DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024606&p_id=6006&seq=1&format=2) it works perfectly.

Before the cable arrived I used DVI, through the [Apple Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter) - adapters with firmware version 1.03 work reliably though 1.02 did not. Apple replaced mine because of this, see support bulletin [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3232?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). It's nice to put the bulky adapter and bulky DVI cable away.